# LaTeX: inserting pictures with same scaling?

Tags: image, latex, png

I want to insert pictures (.png) which I created using ChemDraw. Each picture will basically be just one molecule.
How can I make sure, that when I set the `floatwidth` and the width of `includegraphics` commmand to 1 (or any other value) of linewidth, that all letters/bondlengths etc are the same size in each picture?
At the moment I measure every bondlength with a ruler and adjust the values for the width...not fun.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess in your case it is better to make the source the same size, instead of meddling with LaTeX. I am not too sure other than manual measurement, how else we can achieve what you want.

Comment: in ChemDraw there are not so many options for exporting to .png. I tried scaling every .png in gimp to the same size but that didn't work out either.

Comment: sorry! may not be of much help more